# Error: Multiple children were passed to <Link> with `href` of `/posts` but only one child is supported

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I'm getting this error and am having issues identifying the source. [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag) reference says I can force pass the link to `<a>` tags, if the child is a custom component.

Here's the code:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

function PostList({ posts }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>List of Posts</h1>
      {posts.map((post) => {
        return (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <Link href={`posts/${post.id}`} passHref>
              <h2>
                {post.id} {post.title}
              </h2>
            </Link>
            <hr />
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default PostList

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  const data = await response.json()

  return {
    props: {
      posts: data.slice(0, 3),
    },
  }
}
```

I'm passing `passHref` into the `Link`. What might be causing this error?

Comment: `<h2>` is not likely something you can passHref too. I don't think you want the pass href property. That property is for when the component inside link renders the `<a>` tag.

Comment: @nlta it's interesting, because I'm following this tutorial and it works, here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1XEe-ng57GA&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwgC9mj0qv972IO5DmD-H0ZH&index=23

Comment: @nlta doesn't work with the `<a>` tag or even when I remove the `<h2>` tag. Something is afoot.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

My `Home()`page had an `<a>` tag in the wrong place.

```
import Link from 'next/link'

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Next JS pre-rendering</h1>
      <Link href="/users">
        <a>Users</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/posts">
        <a>Posts</a>
      </Link>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I had the `<a>Posts</a>` after the `<Link>` tag.